# Finding convergent subsequence of $(\sin n)$ in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Convergent subsequence of $(\sin n)$ exists by Bolzanno Weierstrass theorem. I am trying to construct a convergent subsequence of the sequence $(\sin n)$.

**My attempt:** I note that the sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_n=\frac{[2^n\pi]}{2^n}\to \pi,$ where $[]$ is floor function. 
It is because  $ \frac{2^n\pi-1}{2^n}\le \frac{[2^n\pi]}{2^n}\le \frac{2^n\pi}{2^n}\implies x_n\to \pi$.

Define $n_k=[2^k\pi]$. I claim that subsequence $(\sin n_k)$ converges to $0$.

I tried to prove this claim like this: $|\sin n_k|=|\sin (n_k-2^k\pi)|\le|n_k -2^k\pi|=2^k|\frac{n_k}{2^k}-\pi|\to \infty \times 0 $.

How do I proceed from here to conclusively decide convergence of $(\sin n_k)$? And if it turns out to be divergent, how do I construct a convergent subsequence of $(\sin n)$?

Edit: Using "Hurwitz theorem" as suggested by @Gary in comments, $(\sin k_n)$ is convergent. It can be proved as follows: for every $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists N_\epsilon $ such that 
$\frac 1{n}\le \frac 1{N_\epsilon} \lt \sqrt 5 \epsilon \;\forall n\ge N_\epsilon$ 
Hence, by Hurwitz theorem, $|\sin k_n|=|\sin (k_n-\pi)|\le |k_n-\pi|\lt \frac 1{\sqrt 5 n}\lt \epsilon $. Therefore, $\sin k_n\to 0$.

Does there exist any explicit form of $k_n$ as I have tried to construct for $n_k$ by defining $n_k=[2^k\pi]$?

Comment: Just curious, why did not you start with $x_n  = \frac{{\left[ {\pi n} \right]}}{n}$? Why $2^n$?

Comment: @Gary: That works too. I think I wanted denominator to be larger than $n$. :)

Comment: Perhaps you can read about rational approximations of $\pi$ (irrationality measure, especially).

Comment: @Gary: Actually I don't remember the name of that theorem which approximates rational $r$ by prime integers $a_n,b_n$. Can you please suggest that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary. Using Hurwitz's theorem, $(\sin (k_n))$ is convergent. But is there any explicit form of these $k_n's$? For example, in my post I tried to define $n_k$ explicitly using floor function.

Comment: Take successive continued fractions of $\pi$ and ignore denominator. Since numerator is about $3d$ and $d\nearrow$ then numerator will make an increasing sequence too.